# Add parameters to registration: Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have an existing registration controller and view made for an admin panel that was previously made for an app made for iOS and Android. Recently I was tasked with using the `sign_up` of that panel to register all type of users, admin users and users of the applications, since they now want a webpage with the same functionality (The `sign_up` was made to only register admin users on the database , I really don´t know why).
The admin panel has a function to register new normal users, and seeing that, I tried to use the same method in another page copying the methods of the controller it used, using this kind of form `<%= form_for @user do |form| %>`.
The result was that it doesn't allow to register the user if another admin user is not logged in, which is the reason I moved to the original `sign_up` page of the registration controller that devise uses.
I've searched for methods that allow me to use more parameters in the `sign_up` form but failed so far. This is the code of the registration controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

      before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
      prepend_before_action :require_no_authentication, only: [:new, :create, :cancel]

      prepend_before_action :set_minimum_password_length, only: [:new, :edit]

      # GET /resource/sign_up
      def new
        build_resource({})
        yield resource if block_given?
        respond_with resource
      end

      # POST /resource
      def create
        build_resource(sign_up_params)

        resource.save
        yield resource if block_given?
        if resource.persisted?
          if resource.active_for_authentication?
            set_flash_message! :notice, :signed_up
            sign_up(resource_name, resource)
            respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
          else
            set_flash_message! :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}"
            expire_data_after_sign_in!
            respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
          end
        else
          clean_up_passwords resource
          set_minimum_password_length
          respond_with resource
        end
      end

      # GET /resource/edit
      def edit
        render :edit
      end

      # PUT /resource
      # We need to use a copy of the resource because we don't want to change
      # the current user in place.
      def update
        self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)
        prev_unconfirmed_email = resource.unconfirmed_email if resource.respond_to?(:unconfirmed_email)

        resource_updated = update_resource(resource, account_update_params)
        yield resource if block_given?
        if resource_updated
          if is_flashing_format?
            flash_key = update_needs_confirmation?(resource, prev_unconfirmed_email) ?
              :update_needs_confirmation : :updated
            set_flash_message :notice, flash_key
          end
          bypass_sign_in resource, scope: resource_name
          respond_with resource, location: after_update_path_for(resource)
        else
          clean_up_passwords resource
          set_minimum_password_length
          respond_with resource
        end
      end

      # DELETE /resource
      def destroy
        resource.destroy
        Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name)
        set_flash_message! :notice, :destroyed
        yield resource if block_given?
        respond_with_navigational(resource){ redirect_to after_sign_out_path_for(resource_name) }
      end

      # GET /resource/cancel
      # Forces the session data which is usually expired after sign
      # in to be expired now. This is useful if the user wants to
      # cancel oauth signing in/up in the middle of the process,
      # removing all OAuth session data.
      def cancel
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        redirect_to new_registration_path(resource_name)
      end

      protected

        def configure_permitted_parameters
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:nombre_usuario, :apellidos, :tipo,])
      end

      def update_needs_confirmation?(resource, previous)
        resource.respond_to?(:pending_reconfirmation?) &&
          resource.pending_reconfirmation? &&
          previous != resource.unconfirmed_email
      end

      # By default we want to require a password checks on update.
      # You can overwrite this method in your own RegistrationsController.
      def update_resource(resource, params)
        resource.update_with_password(params)
      end

      # Build a devise resource passing in the session. Useful to move
      # temporary session data to the newly created user.
      def build_resource(hash=nil)
        self.resource = resource_class.new_with_session(hash || {}, session)
      end

      # Signs in a user on sign up. You can overwrite this method in your own
      # RegistrationsController.
      def sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      end

      # The path used after sign up. You need to overwrite this method
      # in your own RegistrationsController.
      def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
        after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      end

      # The default url to be used after updating a resource. You need to overwrite
      # this method in your own RegistrationsController.
      def after_update_path_for(resource)
        signed_in_root_path(resource)
      end


        def sign_up_params
        params.require(:usuario).permit(:nombre_usuario, :apellidos, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end

      def account_update_params
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update)
      end

      def translation_scope
        'devise.registrations'
      end
end
```

And this is the form used for the sign_up, new.html.erb

```
    <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <%= devise_error_messages! %>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :nombre_usuario %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :nombre_usuario, autofocus: true %>
      </div>
        <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :apellidos %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :apellidos, autofocus: true %>
      </div>
        <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :tipo %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :tipo, autofocus: true %>
      </div>
     <div class="field">
       <%= f.label :email %><br />
       <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
     </div>    
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password %>
        <% if @minimum_password_length %>
        <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
        <% end %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
      </div>

      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

I just need a solution to this problem without killing what the mobile application uses, I can´t mess too much with the database for that matter.  I'm also new to rails, so I don't really know what else could be the problem.   When I try to run that `sign_up` on the *localhost* it says `NoMethodError` in `Registrations#new`. When you substitute one of the parameters like `:tipo` or `:apellido` for one default authentication parameter like `:email` it works perfectly and no error comes out, so the problem are the extra parameters I try to validate.

Is there some syntax I'm not seeing? Or is it too late to try to use that `sign_up` for every user without killing the mobile apps messing with their models?

Comment: I forgot to mention I´m using devise 4.3.0

Comment: Did you add new params (tipo, apellido) to sign_up_params?

Comment: I just checked and I was missing :tipo, but adding it to sign_up_params changes nothing